# Derivate of the determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, determinant

Is there a simple way to see that $$\frac{d}{dt}\det(\exp(tX))\bigg|_{t=0}=\text{tr}(X)\quad\forall X\in\text{Mat}(n,\mathbb{C})?$$

Of course there are formulas for the derivate of the determinant function but let us assume I don't know any of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ is in Jordan normal form, then the diagonal entries of $e^{tX}$ are $e^{ta_{kk}}$ and $$\det e^{tX}=e^{t\sum a_{kk}}$$